# Создание стольких блоков сколько записей в БД

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-server

Всем привет. Я для тренировки решил сделать справочный сайт со статьями.

Статьи находятся в отдельных div'ах, а сами статьи можно убирать, добавлять и редактировать. Статьи хранятся в базе данных SQL Server.

Отсюда вопрос. Вот у меня в базе данных хранятся id, заголовок и текст статьи. Как мне вывести это на сайт? Как создать столько div'ов с нужным текстом и заголовком, сколько записей в бд?

Comment: Я думаю стоит попробовать и всё получится. Невозможно найти руководство или пример по работе с БД из РНР, который не дает пример вывода информации из базы данных в цикле

Comment: Я работаю с этим впервые. И вообще не понимаю как связать html Файл с php

Comment: И отсюда также вопрос, можно ли это реализовать без php

Answer (score 0):

нашел свой старый код, может поможет. остается подправить в блоки.

```
<?php foreach ($list as $val): ?>
<h3><a href="news/<?=$val['id'] ?>"><?=$val['name'] ?></a></h3>
<p><?=$val['text'] ?></p>
<hr />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

или так

```
foreach ($list as $val) {
    echo '<h3><a href="news/'.$val['id'].'">'.$val['name'].'</a></h3>';
    echo '<p>'.$val['text'].'</p>';
    echo '<hr />';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, благодаря вашему примеру.

Comment: Однако появился другой вопрос:
Можно ли как-то более красиво сделать совмещенный синтаксис php и html? А не пихать для каждой переменной открывающие и закрывающие знаки <?php ?> ? Есть какой-то более красивый и удобный способ?

Comment: @CSharpLooser можно так, подправил. погугли, много разных способов